# How to redirect URLs

Tags: php, url-rewriting

/index.php?Bank=abhyudaya-cooperative-bank has to be rewritten and redirected to

/abhyudaya-cooperative-bank.html and

similarly

http://example.com/index.php?Bank=abhyudaya-cooperative-bank&State=gujarat has to be rewritten and redirected to
http://example.com/abhyudaya-cooperative-bank/gujarat.html

i know it can be done through .htacces file. i m not getting how to do it.
please help me. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code in your .htacess file

Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on

rewritecond %{http_host} ^http://example.com/[nc]

rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://example.com//$1 [r=301,nc]

RewriteRule  ^([0-9A-Za-z'/+_.&;-]+).html$ index.php?Bank=$1

RewriteRule  ^([0-9A-Za-z'/+*.&;-]+)/([0-9A-Za-z'/+*.&;-]+).html$ index.php?Bank=$1&State=$2

Comment: Hie Salokh. thanks for your reply. 

I pasted the same in my .htaccess file., 
http://example.com/index.php?Bank=Abhyudhaya is working but not
http://example.com/Abhyudhaya.html 
Page not Found is coming.

Comment: Hi Tirumalesh reddy, If my answer helped you please approve my answer.

Comment: Salokh. sorry. i wasn't able to do that. 
i joined in stackoverflow today only. i need 'REPUTATION 15' to do that. i have only 1. :(
anyways. thank u soo much :)

Comment: Salokh. one more prob. 
http://example.com/Abhyudaya-bank.html this is working. i can retrive that value of Bank. 

but for this
http://ifscbankscodes.com/Abhyudaya-bank/Gujrat.html this is not working. for bank i m getting value as index.php and state as Gujrat.

Comment: Can you paste the code using to display those variables

Comment: Please remove ; symbol in the last line of .htacess and check it again

Comment: if(isset($_GET['Bank'])){ $BankName = $_GET['Bank']; }
 if(isset($_GET['State'])){ $State = $_GET['State']; }
 if(isset($_GET['District'])){ $District = $_GET['District']; }
 if(isset($_GET['Branch'])){ $Branch = $_GET['Branch']; }
 


echo $BankName ."<br>";
echo $State;

Answer (score 0):

you can add the codes to your .htaccess file. It may work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+).html$  index.php?Bank=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+).html$  index.php?Bank=$1&State=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Good luck.

Comment: Hie vural. thanks for your reply. 

I pasted the same in my .htaccess file., 
http://example.com/index.php?Bank=Abhyudhaya is working but not
http://example.com/Abhyudhaya.html 
Page not Found is coming.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below within your .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.html$  index.php?Bank=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?Bank=$1&State=$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Hie Aram. thanks for your reply. 

I pasted the same in my .htaccess file., 
http://example.com/index.php?Bank=Abhyudhaya is working but not
http://example.com/Abhyudhaya.html 
Page not Found is coming.

Comment: Do you have other rules in your .htaccess?

Comment: No. only these i have